# finding the distance between a plane and a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This might be repetitive butI can't seem to figure it out. Among all the points on the graph of z = 10 - x^2 - y^2 that lie above the plane x + 2y + 3z = 0, find the point farthest from the plane.

I know the point I am looking for has the form of (x, y, 10 - x^2 - y^2) and the normal of the plane is (1,2,3) but from there I don't really know where to go.

Comment: as an suggestion, please format things with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Also, the point furthest from the plane is a bit ambiguous, do you mean vertical distance?

Comment: At the point farthest from the plane, the *tangent plane* of the surface will have to be parallel to the plane. (To see why, think about the $xy$-plane and the point at maximum vertical distance.)

Comment: Yes I see that, so I have that the gradient vector for the surface is (2x, -2y, -1) and that is orthogonal to the tangent of the surface at that point which makes it parallel to the normal. No idea how to proceed from here though